# xslt 1.0 node-set error with Invalid conversion

Tags: xml, xslt, xsd, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I have a problem with xslt in 1.0 version.
My node looks like this

```
...
<Garage>
    <car>
       <color>red</color>
       <color>yellow</color>
       <wheel>left</wheel>
    <car/>
</Garage>
...
```

Then I save child node into variable

```
<xsl:variable name="entries">
    <xsl:if test="$element/Garage/car">
        <xsl:value-of select="$element/Garage/car"/>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:variable>
```

and when I'am using this variable in template

```
    <xsl:template name="entriesToString">
        <xsl:param name="table"/>
        <xsl:for-each select="$table/color">
            <xsl:if test="position() = last()">
                <xsl:value-of select="concat(current(),'/')"/>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:value-of select="concat(current(),',')"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
```

I get error like this

```
ERROR:  'Invalid conversion from 'com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.dom.SimpleResultTreeImpl' to 'node-set'.'
```

Is there any problem with node iteration in xslt ?

Comment: Show a minimal but complete sample to allow us to understand and reproduce the error. I am afraid using `$element` in one snippet without showing how and where it is declared and a second snippet with a named template that is not called in the code we can see doesn't provide the necessary details. On the other hand, one of the known restrictions of XSLT 1 is that a variable where you construct the value inside the `xsl:variable` element instead of using the `select` attribute is a result tree fragment on which you can't use any XPath step expressions.

Comment: Please provide a **reproducible** example. You say that you define a variable named `$entries`, but then you show us code that attempts to process a variable named `$table`.  Also why the `xslt-2.0` tag, when this about XSLT 1.0?

Comment: Furthermore, `xsl:value-of` doesn't select a child node, it creates a text node. It is not clear at all what you want to achieve, I would first think about using a `select` expression to select nodes from the input document before constructing a result tree fragment. If you really need a result tree fragment and want it to contain an element node you select (e.g. `car`), then use `xsl:copy-of`, not `xsl:value-of`. But of course you will need an extension function like `exsl:node-set` to convert the result tree fragment to a node set if you want to use XPath path expressions.

Comment: In the Java world it is rather easy to move to XSLT 2 or 3 using Saxon instead of Xalan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In XSLT 1.0, the `xsl:value-of` instruction creates a **text node** whose value is  the [string-value](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#dt-string-value) of the **first** node in the selected node-set.

In your example, the `$entries` variable is a [result-tree-fragment](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116/#section-Result-Tree-Fragments) that contains the text `"red  yellow left"` (with or without some white-space characters). In order to process a *result-tree-fragment* using the `xsl:for-each` instruction, you must first convert it to a node-set, using a processor-specific extension function. In any case, it wouldn't do you any good in this case, since - as explained above - it contains a **single** text node.

Answer (score 1):

It might suffice to use `<xsl:variable name="entries" select="$element/Garage/car"/>`, that way you have a node-set in XPath/XSLT 1, without the need to use an extension function. The node-set is empty if the path `$element/Garage/car` doesn't select anything, it contains `car` element nodes from `$element` if they exist, i.e. the path `$element/Garage/car` selects something.